# Why does Animal Movement toolbox give SyntaxError: invalid syntax?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, syntaxerror

I found a complete toolbox (Animal Movement tbx, by Regan Sarwas) for my tasks and I tried it.

I had a systematic problem with the codes for all tools (line 1), for exemple:

```
Executing: MinimumConvexPolygon D_VIVEK C:\Users\student\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\D_VIVEK_MinimumConvexPolygon 100 Fixed_Mean # #
Start Time: Sun Apr 13 13:12:47 2014
Running script MinimumConvexPolygon...
Failed script MinimumConvexPolygon...
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (HomeRange_MinimumConvexPolygon.py, line 1)
Failed to execute (MinimumConvexPolygon).
Failed at Sun Apr 13 13:12:47 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.16 seconds)
```

Could anyone help me to understand and correct the problem?

ArcGIS 10.2.1 for Desktop - Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a solution [on your duplicate post on the Esri forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/106540-SyntaxError-in-Tool-Help-to-understand-and-correct-that-error!):

> You just need to delete this part (first three lines of the script):

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit
(Intel)] on win32 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more
information.
>>>
```

> I think the author of this tool meant to delete this portion of the
>   code. This is the text that appears at the top of the Python shell
>   window.